# IoC container for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, inversion-of-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dependency injection framework for Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309711/dependency-injection-framework-for-cocoa)

Is there any IoC container for Objective-C?

Comment: I’ve already added several comments and subsequently deleted them, because I am not sure I understand IoC enough :) But let us try. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Could you expand your question a bit? Objective-C is not Java and some things can be solved in a different way.

Comment: I'm looking for IoC container like Spring. I would like to avoid creating singletons, factories etc on my own...;-)

Comment: Hmmm... I come from .NET land and make heavy use of IoC contrainers (specifically StructureMap). I stumbled across this question wondering if it would be possible to use a container in ObjC... Perhaps Objective-C is too low-level to support the amount of reflection and code generation required to implement a container???

Comment: I don't mean to answer your question with an admonishment, but Cocoa programmers seem to get along fine without factories, singletons, etc..

Comment: @David M.: _without_ singletons? Show me a Cocoa app that doesn't use `NSApplication`.

Comment: @Charles: ObjC is actually _more_ reflective than Java (I don't know enough C# to compare), so it would be super-easy to make an IoC framework using introspection and KVC. Interface Builder is really creating IoC containers, though it's obviously used in limited contexts.

Comment: @Graham Lee - It sure was super easy. Took me ~ 10 days. See here: https://github.com/jasperblues/spring-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

What about the [Objective IOC](http://github.com/mivasi/Objective-IOC) dependecy injection framework?

Answer (score 1):

What about using Interface Builder?

Comment: That was my first thought. Though something with a human-editable persistent format would be beneficial (and let's face it, even XIB isn't comprehensible).

Answer (score 0):

Very very simple IOC container here - [Inverter](https://github.com/aranm/Inverter)