# Dependency Injection framework for the iPhone

Tags: iphone, dependency-injection

I was wondering if there were any dependency injection frameworks for use with development on the iPhone. Being a Java developer by day, I enjoy, and see the benefits of, frameworks like Spring.

You can go part of the way by manually making certain components singletons and tying up the references manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this very similar, almost-dupe [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309711/dependency-injection-framework-for-cocoa).

In summary, you can achieve similar to DI using [Categories](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCategories.html).  Here's a [non-Apple reference](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I see categories as being a form of DI.

Comment: What about a testing category that overrode a method to get a service with a method that returned a mock service instead?

Comment: That's a good example. I think maybe I was fixated with the way Spring allows for collaborators to be injected using autowiring. Actually, what you suggest is also a legitimate expression of dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

There is an dependecy injection library for iphone which support autowiring and more nice features http://github.com/mivasi/Objective-IOC

Answer (score 0):

Very very simple IOC container here - [Inverter](https://github.com/aranm/Inverter)