# Singleton in java

Tags: java, static, singleton, lazy-loading

I just got to read the following code somewhere :

```
public class SingletonObjectDemo {

    private static SingletonObjectDemo singletonObject;
    // Note that the constructor is private
    private SingletonObjectDemo() {
        // Optional Code
    }
    public static SingletonObjectDemo getSingletonObject() {
        if (singletonObject == null) {
            singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
       }
       return singletonObject;
    }
}
```

I need to know what is the need of this part :

```
if (singletonObject == null) {
    singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
}
```

What if we do not use this part of code ? There would still be a single copy of `SingletonObjectDemo`, why do we need this code then ?

Comment: Just so it's said....apparently the Singleton pattern says the constructor should be `protected`.  Something about inheritance.  Although it seems inheritance with singletons would be damn near impossible to do well, that's what the pattern nuts thought up.  Just so it's said.

Comment: That wont work to create a Singleton. If two or more threads call the getSingletonObject() method more instances could be created so you can add synchronize key word to that method. To make it singleton you should also override the Object clone() method.

Comment: @cHao: I took an expert's Design Patterns course from [Dr. Kabutz of JavaSpecialists](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/) (recommended!) He said that sometimes an app needs to choose between various alternative (but related) Singletons, hence the desirability of subclassing ability. Applications will often choose one of the implementing classes at runtime, perhaps via a configuration file and `class.forName` instantiation.

Comment: @Enrique : Can you please explain the need of clone() here ? Thanks.

Comment: @Ishi: The best use would be to throw a CloneNotSupportedException or something (since singletons should never be cloneable -- that'd require two of them existing at once -- but Object has a default clone() method that could easily be turned on by extending the class and implementing Cloneable).

Comment: @Carl Smotricz: Ahh...that does make some sense.  :)  Course, that makes it kinda difficult to implement the singleton pattern entirely in the singleton class, since the class itself shouldn't know about its subclasses.

Comment: @Ishi: clone method is in Object class so every class you create will inherit this method. The users of the singleton can call this method to create copies of the instance

Comment: @cHao: Correct! When I mentioned this, the instructor started handwaving a bit ;) I guess you re-implement the instantiation mechanism individually for each class, but you can do some inheritance on the fields and methods dealing with your actual business data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This class has a field `SingletonObjectDemo singletonObject` that holds the singleton instance. Now there are two possible strategies -

1 - You do eager initialization of the object with the declaration -

```
private static SingletonObjectDemo singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
```

This will cause your singleton object to be initialized the moment the class is loaded. The downside of this strategy is that if you have many singletons, they will all be initialized and occupying memory even when they are not needed yet.

2 - You do lazy initialization of the object i.e. initialize it when the first call to `getSingletonObject()` is made -

```
// note that this initializes the object to null by default
private static SingletonObjectDemo singletonObject;
```

...

```
if (singletonObject == null) {
        singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
    }
```

This saves you the memory until the singleton is really needed. The downside of this strategy is that the first invocation of the method may see slightly worse response time as it will have to initialize the obejct before returning it.

Comment: Thank you ! I was exactly looking for this answer.

Comment: Also would like to add, as others have pointed out, that you should make the `getSingletonObject()` method `synchronized` with the second strategy to make it thread-safe, if running the code in a multi-threaded env. If it is not synchronized and two threads invoke the method at the same time when the object is still null, both might end up creating a new instance each.

Comment: Why would the class be loaded before it is needed?

Comment: The time that a class is loaded into the jvm is dependent on the jvm implementation. The spec itself doesn't specify when classes are loaded. This means that it is almost impossible to accurately predict when a class is loaded. I, and I think most people, assume worst case performance and prefer the second option. This way, we can guarantee that the object is not consuming memory until we need it.

Answer (score 9):

#### On lazy vs eager initialization

The `if` statement is an implementation of the [lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization) technique.

A more explicit version is as follows:

```
private boolean firstTime = true;
private Stuff stuff;

public Stuff gimmeStuff() {
   if (firstTime) {
      firstTime = false;
      stuff = new Stuff();
   }
   return stuff;
}
```

What happens is that the very first time `gimmeStuff()` is invoked, `firstTime` would be `true`, so `stuff` would be initialized to `new Stuff()`. On subsequent invokations, `firstTime` would be `false`, so `new Stuff()` would no longer be called.

Thus, `stuff` is initialized "lazily". It's not actually initialized until the very first time it's needed.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization)
- [Wikipedia/Initialization on demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom)

---

#### On thread safety

It needs to be said that the snippet is not thread-safe. If there are multiple threads, then in some [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) `new SingletonObjectDemo()` may be invoked several times.

One solution is to make `synchronized getSingletonObject()` method. This does, however, have a synchronization overhead on *ALL* calls to `getSingletonObject()`. The so-called [double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) idiom is then used to try to remedy this, but in Java, this idiom does not actually work until J2SE 5.0 with the introduction of `volatile` keyword in the new memory model.

Needless to say that proper enforcement of singleton pattern isn't a trivial thing.

#### See also

- [developerWorks/Java: Double-checked locking and the Singleton pattern -- A comprehensive look at this broken programming idiom](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl.html)
- [Wikipedia/Double-checked locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)

#### Related questions

- [synchronized block vs synchronized method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574240/synchronized-block-vs-synchronized-method)

---

#### Effective Java 2nd Edition

Here's what the book has to say on these subjects:

*Item 71: Use lazy initialization judiciously*

> As is the case for most optimizations, the best advice for lazy initialization is "don't do it unless you need to". Lazy initialization is a double-edged sword. It decreases the cost of initializing a class or creating an instance, at the expense of increasing the cost of accessing a lazily initialized field. Depending on what fraction of lazily initialized fields eventually require initialization, how expensive it is to initialize them, and how often each field is accessed, lazy initialization (like many "optimizations" actually harm performance).
>
> In the presence of multiple threads, lazy initialization is tricky. If two or more threads share a lazily initialized field, it is critical that some form of synchronization be employed, or severe bugs can result.
>
> Under most circumstances, normal initialization is preferable to lazy initialization.

*Item 3: Enforce the singleton property with a private constructor or an `enum` type*

> As of release 1.5. there is a third approach to implementing singletons. Simply make an enum type with one element.  [...] This approach is functionally equivalent to the `public` field approach, except that it's more concise, provides the serialization mechanism for free, and provides ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or reflection-based attacks.
>
> [...] A single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton.

#### Related questions

On `enum` singleton/Java implementation:

- [Efficient way to implement singleton pattern in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java)
- [Java Enum Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427902/java-enum-singleton)
- [Comparing Java enum members: == or equals() ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1750435/comparing-java-enum-members-or-equals)
- [Thread safety in Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912281/thread-safety-in-singleton/)

On singleton pattern merits and alternatives:

- [On Design Patterns: When to use the Singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228164/on-design-patterns-when-to-use-the-singleton)
- [Purpose of singletons in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551112/purpose-of-singletons-in-programming)
- [What is so bad about Singletons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons)
- [Singletons: good design or a crutch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831/singletons-good-design-or-a-crutch)
- [What’s Alternative to Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300655/whats-alternative-to-singleton)
- [Singleton: How should it be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 4):

> What if we do not use this part of code ? There would still be a single copy of SingletonObjectDemo, why do we need this code then ?

The idea is to lazy-load the singleton i.e. to load the instance **only when actually needed**. Why would you want to do that? Well, Bob Lee summarizes this pretty well in [Lazy Loading Singletons](http://crazybob.org/2007/01/lazy-loading-singletons.html):

> In production, you typically want to eagerly load all your singletons so you catch errors early and take any performance hit up front, but in tests and during development, you only want to load what you absolutely need so as not to waste time.

But the implementation you're showing is broken, it is not thread safe and two concurrent threads could actually create two instances. The **best** way to make your lazy loaded singleton thread safe would be to use the [Initialization on Demand Holder (IODH) idiom](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#dcl) which is very simple and has **zero** synchronization overhead. Quoting Effective Java, *Item 71: Use lazy initialization judiciously* (emphasis is not mine):

> **If you need to use lazy initialization for performance on a
>   static field, use the *lazy
>   initialization holder class idiom***.
>   This idiom (also known as the
>   *initialize-on-demand holder class idiom*) exploits the guarantee that a
>   class will not be initialized until it
>   is used [JLS, 12.4.1]. Here’s how it
>   looks:
>
> ```
> // Lazy initialization holder class idiom for static fields
> private static class FieldHolder {
>     static final FieldType field = computeFieldValue();
> }
> static FieldType getField() { return FieldHolder.field; }
> ```
>
> When the `getField` method is invoked
>   for the first time, it reads
>   `FieldHolder.field` for the first
>   time, causing the `FieldHolder` class
>   to get initialized. The beauty of this
>   idiom is that the `getField` method is
>   not synchronized and performs only a
>   field access, so lazy initialization
>   adds practically nothing to the cost
>   of access. A modern VM will
>   synchronize field access only to
>   initialize the class. Once the class
>   is initialized, the VM will patch the
>   code so that subsequent access to the
>   field does not involve any testing or
>   synchronization.

#### See also

- Item 66: Synchronize access to shared mutable data - Effective Java 2nd edition
- Item 71: Use lazy initialization judiciously - Effective Java 2nd edition
- [Does the new memory model fix the "double-checked locking" problem?](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#dcl)

Answer (score 3):

The 2 lines check whether or not the one and only singleton is created and if not they will create the singleton instance. If the instance does exist already nothing is done and it is returned. The singleton instance is created the first time it is needed on-demand, not when the application initialises.

Note that your code contains a **race-condition** error. When 2 threads enter concurrently, the singleton object can be allocated twice. This can be fixed by synchronizing the method like so:

```
public static synchronized SingletonObjectDemo getSingletonObject() {
    if (singletonObject == null) {
        singletonObject = new SingletonObjectDemo();
    }
    return singletonObject;
}
```

Btw, to come back to your question, the line:

```
private static SingletonObjectDemo singletonObject;
```

declares a static reference but it won't acvtually allocate an instance, the reference is set to `null` by the Java compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The class as given doesn't create the first instance of the object until it is requested.  The `private static` field is `null` until the first request, then an instance of the object is constructed and stored there.  Subsequent requests return the same object.

If you remove those two lines of code, you would never actually create the initial instance, so you would always be returning `null`.

Answer (score 0):

This code

- is responsible for creating the first object
- prevents from creating another

Answer (score 0):

At first singletonObject is set to null. The idea behind the singleton is to initialize that object first time when someone calls getSingletonObject(). If you don't call constructor in that part the variable will always be null.