# why I should prefer Singleton class over other

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

I was going through the singleton design pattern, I have a query regarding singleton pattern.
-why there is need to create only one object for a class and what is the actual use of using singleton pattern?
-what are the pros and cons for using singleton class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86582/singleton-how-should-it-be-used?rq=1

Comment: Can you please help me with the concept of Early Instantiation and Lazy Instantiation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Purpose of singletons in programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551112/purpose-of-singletons-in-programming)