# Make a singleton class in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to make a Singleton class constructor in Javascript.
But I am getting an error. 
Taking `Java` analogy, what I did was :

```
var ob1 = (function getSingleton() {
    var privateData;
    if(this.privateData !== null) {
        this.privateData = new getSingleton();
        return this.privateData;
    }
})();
```

But I am getting the following:

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

What am I conceptually doing wrong? 
Or, how can it be made perfect?

Comment: `this.privateData = new getSingleton();` is recursively creating a new instance, hence the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simplest/Cleanest way to implement singleton in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1479319/simplest-cleanest-way-to-implement-singleton-in-javascript)

Comment: @briosheje But I am checking right if it's not null? So once the function executes, it creates the instance and assigns it. Going forward, it should not be creating instances. What am I missing here ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder: No, because you are creating a **new** object, which will be, by default, empty. That's not the way you should do it, check Serge's link to properly implement a singleton class. You should **never ever** have a recursive constructor in this situation. About your question, there are two additional errors: `var privateData` is different from `this.privateData`. Moreover, `this.privateData` is `undefined`, not null. Hence the maximum call stack size exceeded (because it's `undefined`, which is different from `null`)

Comment: Why do you need a singleton? Why not just make ob1 an instance of the object and then be done with it? Aren't they just the "...political correct name for global variables on OO"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551112/purpose-of-singletons-in-programming