# Class auto-wiring in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, design-patterns, inversion-of-control

From past thread: [Dependency injection framework for Cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309711/dependency-injection-framework-for-cocoa), although it was said that IoC framework is not needed to dynamic language such as Obj-C, but people often missed one of the core feature - **wiring of class at runtime**., they are important for `compiled language` such as Obj-C

There are some so existing so called IoC containers for Obj-C such as `objection` which still require you to hack the code in order to change the implementation.

Are there any similar tool like `spring` you can alter the `implementations` and auto-wire for example, using an XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use InterfaceBuilder? It's basically what it does. The objects don't need to be UI components.

Comment: It's reasonably well documented, and you can in fact edit it directly or generate the files yourself from code. http://www.monobjc.net/index.php?page=xib-file-format